# Using Grid with Categories

Tags: grid, categories

I'm wondering how to use categories with Grid in a particular circumstance, or if that is really the best way to go.

Specifically, I'm doing a website for a restaurant and they want to be able to update their menu on a daily basis, so I want to use a Grid fieldtype for this.

So the question: is it possible to have a single Grid with the edit screen like this, with "Appetizer" and "Entrée" as categories?:

```
Appetizer
 -- item1
 -- item2
 -- item3
Entrée
 -- item1
 -- item2
 -- item3
```

Or does it make more sense to just have Appetizer, Entrée, etc. as separate Grid fields?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories can only be assigned to entries, not fields. You're better off to create a new Grid field for each part of the menu (Appetizers, Entrées, etc), so that you can enter each menu item row-by-row under each section.

Alternately, you could have a checkbox column in your grid called "Heading?", which indicates that that articular row is is a heading/divider in the menu, then design your template accordingly.